# C# 'contains' with a more accurate match

Tags: c#, xml

I have these xml elements representing a sitemap:

```
<page path="/accountadmin/getusers/userdetails" en="Account Admin/Manage Users/User Details">
</page>
<page path="/accountadmin/getusers" en="Account Admin/Manage Users">
</page>  
<page path="/accountadmin" en="Account Admin">
</page>
```

when I have the following relative url that is the current page:

```
/accountadmin/getusers/userdetails/mz
```

I want to match the xml path: `path="/accountadmin/getusers/userdetails"`
currently I have to reorder the paths so that smaller match occures last.

I use this linq query:

```
string localPath = (from page in sitemap.Doc.Descendants("page")
                    where relativePath.StartsWith((string)page.Attribute("path"))
                    select (string)page.Attribute(lang)).FirstOrDefault();
```

using either startswith or contains is no different. How to use a regex or a simpler way so that with any order the linq returns the correct match?

Comment: And what is the problem? Does your query bring the wrong result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you include "normal" Linq-to-Objects you can compare and store the best match with `Aggregate`, a benefit of which is you don't need multiple enumerations or to order the data:

```
var relativeUrl = "/accountadmin/getusers/userdetails/mz";
var bestMatch = sitemap.Doc.Descendants("page").Aggregate("", (tmp, page) =>
    page.Attribute("path")?.Value is { } p && relativeUrl.StartsWith(p) && p.Length > tmp.Length ? p : tmp);

Console.WriteLine("bestMatch: {0}", bestMatch);
```

Since you don't seem to want the path attribute itself, but rather another attribute 'lang' (unless it was a typo) from the same page-element, this would find that other Attribute 'lang':

```
var (el, len) = (default(XElement), 0);
var bestMatch = sitemap.Doc.Descendants("page").Aggregate((el, len), (tmp, page) =>
    page.Attribute("path")?.Value is { } p && relativeUrl.StartsWith(p)
   && p.Length > tmp.len ? (page, p.Length) : tmp).el.Attribute(lang);
```

Comment: yes it works, yet the basic idea is choosing the path with the most length as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

```
string localPath = sitemap.Doc.Descendants("page")
    .Where(page => relativePath.StartsWith(page.Attribute("path").Value))
    .MaxBy(page => page.Attribute("path").Value)
    .Attribute(lang).Value;
```

This code finds the value with the longest length using the `MaxBy` method, which is much more efficient than sorting.

Answer (score -1):

I found a simple way to do this using this linq expression, The idea is using the match with the longest length:

```
string localPath = (from page in sitemap.Doc.Descendants("page")
                    where relativePath.StartsWith((string)page.Attribute("path"))
                    orderby ((string)page.Attribute("path")).Length descending
                    select (string)page.Attribute(lang)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Now when I randomly order xml nodes the match is correct.

Comment: I don't understand the minus point for my answer since this answer works good and is also efficient. @persongaveminus is there any reason that this code is wrong?